# How sum all distance and travel time from waypoints, origin and destination

Tags: java, android

I am building an app in which it shows a route with waypoints, and display total travel time and distance, but the problem is that not sum all waypoints, not show total distance and total time, only show me one leg, i need sum all waypoints with the origin and destination, how i do?

[JSON Code](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=6.3415247,-75.5577208&destination=6.3498971,-75.5567523&waypoints=optimize:true%7C6.3453442,-75.5516705%7C6.3483309,-75.5495995%7C6.3456380,-75.5491314%7C6.3455911,-75.5470564%7C6.3371096,-75.5501655%7C6.3415247,-75.5577208)

Below fragment code of my **Directionfinder.java**, I try to do it like that, but it does not work

```
private void parseJSon(String data) throws JSONException {
        if (data == null)
            return;

        List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
       long totalDistance = 0;
       int totalSeconds = 0;

       JSONObject jsonDistance = null;
       JSONObject jsonDuration = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
            Route route = new Route();

            JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
           // JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(0);

           // JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");
          //  JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");



            for (int j = 0; j < jsonLegs.length(); j++) {

                jsonDistance = ((JSONObject) jsonLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");

                totalDistance = totalDistance + Long.parseLong(jsonDistance.getString("value"));

                /** Getting duration from the json data */
                jsonDuration = ((JSONObject) jsonLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                totalSeconds = totalSeconds + Integer.parseInt(jsonDuration.getString("value"));




            }
            route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
            route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
            //route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
            //route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
          //  route.endAddress = jsonLeg.getString("end_address");
            //route.startAddress = jsonLeg.getString("start_address");
            //route.startLocation = new LatLng(jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            //route.endLocation = new LatLng(jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

            routes.add(route);
        }

       double dist = totalDistance / 1000.0;
       Log.d("distance", "Calculated distance:" + dist);

       int days = totalSeconds / 86400;
       int hours = (totalSeconds - days * 86400) / 3600;
       int minutes = (totalSeconds - days * 86400 - hours * 3600) / 60;
       int seconds = totalSeconds - days * 86400 - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
       Log.d("duration", days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " mins" + seconds + " seconds");


       listener.onDirectionFinderSuccess(routes);
    }
```

Comment: post your json code

Comment: ok i post JSON Link

Comment: what is your expected and actual output?

Comment: Im sorry my bad english, i need get Total Time and Total distance, from waypoints and origin an destination

Comment: you'll get that in `totalDistance` and `totalSeconds` as per calculation

Comment: Why `route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));` not show **totalDistance** en textview?,

Answer (score 0):

Yep , you have to use calculated distance and time value while adding it to route as in

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
            Route route = new Route();

            JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
           // JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(0);

           // JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");
          //  JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");

           totalDistance = 0;
           totalSeconds = 0; //<-- reset for each loop

            for (int j = 0; j < jsonLegs.length(); j++) {

                jsonDistance = ((JSONObject) jsonLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");

                totalDistance = totalDistance + Long.parseLong(jsonDistance.getString("value"));

                /** Getting duration from the json data */
                jsonDuration = ((JSONObject) jsonLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                totalSeconds = totalSeconds + Integer.parseInt(jsonDuration.getString("value"));
            }
             //adding the calculated values
            route.distance = new Distance("totalDistance",totalDistance);
            route.duration = new Duration("Total Time",totalSeconds); 

            route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

            routes.add(route);
        }
```

Comment: im sorry i again, the textview now display only totalDistance like text, but not show the value total in numbers